# How to save base64 image to another project using API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I made a new project for API and I want to store image in original project folder so..

I get a base64 image and I want to save it in original project and store image path in database.

my code is

```
string filePath = "";
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(base64Image))
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    string imgname =  ran.Next(1000000).ToString();//OriginalProjectPath= "http://10.0.0.200:5002"
    filePath = OriginalProjectPath + "/image/note_img/" + imgname + ".png";
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "original project folder" and  and how that relates to `OriginalProjectPath `. To better your chances of a quality answer, try rephrasing a clear question and adding more detail.

Comment: Is the comment `//OriginalProjectPath= "http://10.0.0.200:5002"` indicating you are trying to save this locally with that value within the file name?

Comment: yes I want to save it to "http://10.0.0.200:5002" locally now ,, but i want it to work even if it's in different server

Answer (score 0):

You are writing files using a HTTP. You should rather use FTP and configure 10.0.0.200:5002 to accept FTP.

Or you should have an API on 10.0.0.200:5002 to accept a HTTP with binary payload. In this case, the binary payload is your image file base64.